# RelaxNG (rnc) schema to extend XHTML

Tags: emacs, xhtml, xsd, relaxng

I would like to edit XHTML files using Emacs' [nxml-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NxmlMode) which can use [rnc](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/rnc/) schemas for on the fly validation. This is all built in to newer Emacs versions.

However, my XHTML files contain elements from another schema. So <foo:foo> tags are valid, but only within the <xhtml:head> of the document.

Currently, nxml complains because the XHTML schema it is using does not describe the foo tag. How do I create a new schema which describes the foo tag in relation to the existing XHTML schema, and how do I apply that schema automatically using [schema locating rules](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/relaxng/nxml/schemaloc.html) in the schemas.xml file?

ie: I would like to validate a document using two schemas simultaneously: the built-in XHTML rules, and some custom rules which add certain namespaced tags.

Answer (score 2):

[Validator.nu](http://validator.nu/) has a [preset schema](http://s.validator.nu/xhtml1-rdf-svg-mathml.rnc) that is modified from the the XHTML schema set originally developed by James Clark and one of the additions is rdf:RDF in head, so the schema might be useful to study.

(I have no experience with nxml-mode schema location issues.)

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1: I believe that you don't want two schemas here, but rather one schema that "include"s another, combined with the overriding/combination rules described in section 9.2 of [the RelaxNG tutorial](http://www.relaxng.org/compact-tutorial-20030326.html). I'm wrestling with this myself.

Problem 2: I can give you a better answer to the second problem; nxml-mode looks in one of a number of locations for a "schemas.xml" file that performs pattern-matching to associate files with schemas. For the simplest possible mapping, I have this file in the same dir as the xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<locatingRules xmlns="http://thaiopensource.com/ns/locating-rules/1.0">
  <uri resource="auto.xml" uri="lab.rnc"/>
</locatingRules>
```

This file associates the "auto.xml" file with the "lab.rnc" specification.

Answer (score 2):

The W3C has just the thing. For example, here is the rng for XHTML+RDFa:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- XHTML+RDFa 1.0 -->

<grammar ns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
         datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">

<include href="xhtml-datatypes-1.rng"/>
<include href="xhtml-attribs-1.rng"/>
<include href="xhtml-text-1.rng"/>
<include href="xhtml-list-1.rng"/>
<include href="xhtml-object-1.rng"/>
<include href="xhtml-pres-1.rng"/>
<include href="xhtml-edit-1.rng"/>
<include href="xhtml-bdo-1.rng"/>
<include href="xhtml-form-1.rng"/>
<include href="xhtml-table-1.rng"/>
<include href="xhtml-image-1.rng"/>
<include href="xhtml-ssismap-1.rng"/>
<include href="xhtml-events-1.rng"/>
<include href="xhtml-inlstyle-1.rng"/>
<include href="xhtml-base-1.rng"/>
<include href="xhtml-ruby-1.rng"/>
<include href="xhtml-metaAttributes-1.rng"/>

<define name="xhtml.Common.attrib" combine="interleave">
  <optional>
    <attribute name="href">
      <ref name="xhtml.URI.datatype"/>
    </attribute>
  </optional>
  <ref name="xhtml.Metainformation.attrib"/>
</define>

<include href="xhtml-hypertext-1.rng">
    <define name="xhtml.a.attlist">
      <ref name="xhtml.Common.attrib"/>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="charset">
          <ref name="xhtml.Charset.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="type">
          <ref name="xhtml.ContentType.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="hreflang">
          <ref name="xhtml.LanguageCode.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="accesskey">
          <ref name="xhtml.Character.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="tabindex">
          <ref name="xhtml.Number.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
    </define>
</include>

<include href="xhtml-link-1.rng">
    <define name="xhtml.link.attlist">
      <ref name="xhtml.Common.attrib"/>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="charset">
          <ref name="xhtml.Charset.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="hreflang">
          <ref name="xhtml.LanguageCode.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="type">
          <ref name="xhtml.ContentType.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="media">
          <ref name="xhtml.MediaDesc.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
    </define>
</include>

<include href="xhtml-meta-1.rng">
    <define name="xhtml.meta.attlist">
      <ref name="xhtml.Common.attrib"/>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="http-equiv">
          <data type="NMTOKEN"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="name">
          <data type="NMTOKEN"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="scheme">
          <text/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
    </define>
</include>

<include href="xhtml-script-1.rng">
    <define name="xhtml.script.attlist">
      <ref name="xhtml.id.attrib"/>
      <ref name="xhtml.Metainformation.attrib"/>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="href">
          <ref name="xhtml.URI.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="charset">
          <ref name="xhtml.Charset.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <attribute name="type">
        <ref name="xhtml.ContentType.datatype"/>
      </attribute>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="src">
          <ref name="xhtml.URI.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="defer">
          <value>defer</value>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="xml:space">
          <value>preserve</value>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
    </define>
</include>

<include href="xhtml-style-1.rng">
    <define name="xhtml.style.attlist">
      <ref name="xhtml.title.attrib"/>
      <ref name="xhtml.I18n.attrib"/>
      <ref name="xhtml.id.attrib"/>
      <ref name="xhtml.Metainformation.attrib"/>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="href">
          <ref name="xhtml.URI.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <attribute name="type">
        <ref name="xhtml.ContentType.datatype"/>
      </attribute>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="media">
          <ref name="xhtml.MediaDesc.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <!-- <optional>
        <attribute name="xml:space">
          <value>preserve</value>
        </attribute>
      </optional> -->
    </define>
</include>

<include href="xhtml-csismap-1.rng">
    <define name="xhtml.area.attlist">
      <ref name="xhtml.Common.attrib"/>
      <ref name="xhtml.shape.attrib"/>
      <ref name="xhtml.coords.attrib"/>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="nohref">
          <value>nohref</value>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <attribute name="alt">
        <ref name="xhtml.Text.datatype"/>
      </attribute>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="tabindex">
          <ref name="xhtml.Number.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="accesskey">
          <ref name="xhtml.Character.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
    </define>
</include>

<include href="xhtml-param-1.rng">
    <define name="xhtml.param.attlist">
      <ref name="xhtml.id.attrib"/>
      <ref name="xhtml.Metainformation.attrib"/>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="href">
          <ref name="xhtml.URI.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <attribute name="name"/>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="value"/>
      </optional>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="valuetype">
          <choice>
        <value>data</value>
        <value>ref</value>
        <value>object</value>
          </choice>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
      <optional>
        <attribute name="type">
          <ref name="xhtml.ContentType.datatype"/>
        </attribute>
      </optional>
    </define>
</include>

<include href="xhtml-struct-1.rng">
    <define name="xhtml.title.attlist">
      <ref name="xhtml.Common.attrib"/>
    </define>

    <define name="xhtml.head.attlist">
      <ref name="xhtml.Common.attrib"/>
      <ref name="xhtml.profile.attlist"/>
    </define>

    <define name="xhtml.html.attlist">
      <ref name="xhtml.XHTML.version.attrib"/>
      <ref name="xhtml.Common.attrib"/>
    </define>
</include>

</grammar>
```

**References**

- [XHTML Modularization for RelaxNG:Techniques for using RelaxNG to define and extend XHTML](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2010/xhtml-m12n-relaxng-20101216/)